# Laravel 8: Missing required parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to send some data to a web route like this:

`<form action="{{ route('questions.answers', $show->id, $show->user->name) }}" method="POST">`

And then on `web.php`, I added this:

`Route::post('questions/{question}{asker}/answer' , [QuestionController::class, 'postAnswer'])->name('questions.answers');`

But now it says:

**Missing required parameter for [Route: questions.answers]**

So what is going wrong here ? How can I pass `$show->id` and `$show->user->name` to `questions.answers` route ?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How would it identify - `{question}{asker}`?

Comment: @SougataBose I have passed `{{ route('questions.answers', $show->id, $show->user->name) }}` at form action, is that wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass `answer` as parameter, you can use the below code:

**Your Blade File**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('questions.answers', ['question' => '', 'asker' => '', 'answer' => '']) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    //---Your Data
</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('questions/{question}/{asker}/{answer}' , [QuestionController::class, 'postAnswer'])->name('questions.answers');
```

And if you want to send the answer in your form use this code:

**Your Blade File**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('questions.answers', ['question' => '', 'asker' => '']) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    //---Your Answer Here
</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('questions/{question}/{asker}' , [QuestionController::class, 'postAnswer'])->name('questions.answers');
```

Comment: Thank u, would u mind check out my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67277505/laravel-8-data-truncated-for-column

Comment: No problem, I have added the answer, see if it solve your problem.