# Laravel 8: Data truncated for column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm making a forum with Laravel 8 and in this forum, for posting answers of questions, I made this form:

```
<form action="{{ route('questions.answers', ['question' => $show->id, 'asker' => $show->user->name]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="mb-4">
        <textarea name="answer" id="answer" class="form-control BSinaBold" rows="7" placeholder="Write down answer"></textarea
        @error('answer')
            <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                {{ $message }}
            </div>
        @enderror
    </div>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

And added this also to `web.php`:

```
Route::post('questions/{question}{asker}/answer' , [QuestionController::class, 'postAnswer'])->name('questions.answers');
```

And finally, here is `postAnswer` method:

```
public function postAnswer($id,$name) {
    $validate_data = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
        'answer' => 'required',
    ])->validated();

    $answer = Answer::create([
        'answer' => $validate_data['answer'],
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'question_id' => $id,
    ]);    
    $name->notify(new RepliedToThread($id));

    return back();
}
```

So the `$id` variable here means the question id and `$name` is the username of the person who has asked the question.

But now I get this error somehow:

**Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'question_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `answers` (`answer`, `user_id`, `question_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (ETC)**

So what is going wrong here? How can I fix this issue?

If you know how, please let me know, I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

`answers` table structure:

[image]

Comment: What data types are your DB columns?

Comment: @Aless55 I just added a picture of it

Comment: You already try this?
`public function postAnswer($request, $id, $name)`. I think your $request is inside your $id variable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the following code:

**Blade File**

```
<form action="{{ route('questions.answers', ['question' => $show->id, 'asker' => $show->user->id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="mb-4">
        <textarea name="answer" id="answer" class="form-control BSinaBold" rows="7" placeholder="Write down answer"></textarea>
        @error('answer')
            <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                {{ $message }}
            </div>
        @enderror
    </div>
    </br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('questions/{question}/{asker}', [QuestionController::class, 'postAnswer'])->name('questions.answers');
```

**postAnswer**

```
public function postAnswer(Request $request, $question, $asker) {
    $validate_data = $request->validate([
        'answer' => 'required',
    ]);

    $answer = Answer::create([
        'answer' => $request->answer,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'question_id' => $question,
    ]);

    $asker->notify(new RepliedToThread($question));

    return back();
}
```

Hope you get your answer.

Comment: It works and adds the answer but now shows this error: `Call to a member function notify() on string`

Comment: I just added it but still shows me that error!

Comment: Update your `postAnswer`, I have updated my answer.

Comment: It will still give the same error since he is giving `'asker' => $show->user->name` which is a string, before notifying you should initialize your model, like Model::where('name', $asker) in this situation this is not correct, so you need to pass askers id instead of name and inside the controller, you should initialize your model with id, and then notify. @KKKKKK

Comment: @ibrahim-dogan I also tried `show->user->id` but still shows the same error. What else do I need to do to initialize id ?

Comment: When I use `auth()->user()->notify(new RepliedToThread($question));` it works fine!

Comment: Good, that you got your answer.

Comment: @HedayatullahSarwary The thing is I don't want to notify any authenticated user, I need to notify the person who has asked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67277920/laravel-8-call-to-a-member-function-notify-on-string

Comment: Ok, let me see.

Comment: Have you changed your view `'asker' => $show->user->name` to `'asker' => $show->user->id`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231639/discussion-between-kkk-kkk-and-hedayatullah-sarwary).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try separating your route URL? `{question}/{asker}`:

```
Route::post('questions/{question}/{asker}' , [QuestionController::class, 'postAnswer'])->name('questions.answers');
```

If it works you can also try with `-` or `_` instead of `/`.