# Laravel 8: Call to a member function notify() on string

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to make a forum and now I wanted to send a notification to a user who has asked a question whenever someone answered that question.

So in order to do that, I added this to the Controller:

```
public function postAnswer(Request $request, $question, $asker) {
        $validate_data = $request->validate([
            'answer' => 'required',
        ]);

        $answer = Answer::create([
            'answer' => $request->answer,
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'question_id' => $question,
        ]);

        $asker->notify(new RepliedToThread($question));

        return back();
    }
```

So the `$question` is the **question id** and `$asker` is the **user id** of the person who has asked the question.

But now I get this error:

**Call to a member function notify() on string**

Now the interesting part is that, when I use `auth()->user()->notify(new RepliedToThread($question));`, it is working fine!

But I don't want to notify any authenticated user, I need to notify the person who has asked question, that's why I tried passding `$asker`...

So if you know how to solve this question, please let me know...

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys.

Thanks in advance.

> Blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('questions.answers', ['question' => $show->id, 'asker' => $show->user->id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="mb-4">
        <textarea name="answer" id="answer" class="form-control BSinaBold" rows="7" placeholder="Write down answer"></textarea>
        @error('answer')
            <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
                {{ $message }}
            </div>
        @enderror
    </div>
    </br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: where do you send that $asker to this function? put that code

Comment: obviously $asker that you are sending to this function is not instant of user model

Comment: @miladhedayatpoor I just added the form blade

Comment: now you can use : $asker = User::find($asker); and your problem is gone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `asker` is just an id, you should take the other information of the `asker` from the user table and after that pass your notification to the `asker`.

```
$asker = User::findOrFail($asker);
$asker->notify(new RepliedToThread($question));
```

Comment: This is a correct solution, I just want to point out that one could and should use route model binding so that the framework does the model querying work for one. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you said, the problem is `$asker`. This parameter should be an instance from `User` model but the error implies it is string.

In your form change the form tag:

```
<form action="{{ route('questions.answers', ['question' => $show->id, 'asker' => $show->user]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Remove the `id` after `user`.

Answer (score 2):

make sure your `Answer.php` have `use Notifiable;` imported

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#using-the-notifiable-trait

then only you can call `notify()` function from `Answer` model instance

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$asker` is just a string, its just the `id`value of the user.
I recommend that you use laravels route model binding. The passed parameters `$querstion` and `$asker` are automatically queried from the database.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding

Afterwards you can access the question id normally and you have the notifiable user model.

```php
public function postAnswer(Request $request, Question $question, User $asker) {
   $validate_data = $request->validate([
            'answer' => 'required',
        ]);

        $answer = Answer::create([
            'answer' => $request->answer,
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'question_id' => $question->id,
        ]);

        $asker = User::find($asker);
        $asker->notify(new RepliedToThread($question));

        return back();
}
```